# How to install apk using PackageManager written in java?

Tags: java, android, installation, apk

I have an android application which updates itself from a server, if new version of the apk is present.

The problem is, it is now not working on devices running android 10 and higher. The root cause of the problem is that ACTION_VIEW is deprecated, and no longer supported since android 10. Here is the legacy code which is not working:

```
  private void installapk(File file) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Installing new version...");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        // Otherwise will throw exception, have to install it in new task
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

So after searching for a while now, it seems the only option I have left is to use packagemanager class to do the job. I found this example, which compiles and runs without giving any error message, but it seems like it does nothing.

```
 public static void install(Context context, String packageName, File file) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            PackageInstaller.Session session = null;
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(file);

                PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
                PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                        PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
                //
                params.setAppPackageName(packageName);

                // set params
                int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
                session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
                out = session.openWrite(file.getName(), 0, -1);
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
                int bytes_read;
                while((bytes_read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
                }

                session.fsync(out);
                in.close();
                out.close();

                session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId, ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } finally {

                ;
            }
        }
    } 


   private static IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId, String action) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, sessionId, new Intent(action), 0);
        return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
    }
```

This code runs fine, but as I said, nothing happens as a result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE?

Comment: As long as I know, it is also deprecated.